# Parsing 3 parameters from view (update form) to controller laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a simple code. Now I want to make update form and using 3 parameters. But it getting strange error.. Here's my code

**view: moreDetails.blade.php**

```
<form  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/moredetails/update', $new->proyek_id, $new->laporan_id, $new->id_fisik_rencana) }} " >
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">                        

    <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label">Omzet Kontrak Awal Porsi Rencana</label>
       <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" class="span6 " value="{{ $new->omzet_kontrak_awal_porsi_rencana }}" name="omzet_kontrak_awal_porsi_rencana" />
       </div>
    </div> and many more........



    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**controller: ProjectController.php**

```
public function moredetails1(Request $request, $pr_id, $id_laporan, $id_fisik_rencana) {
  $project = FisikRencana::find($id_fisik_rencana);
  // dd($project);
  FisikRencana::find($laporan_id)->update($request->all());
}
```

and in my route

```
Route::put('/moredetails/update/{pr_id}/{id_laporan}/{id_fisik_rencana}','ProjectController@moredetails1');
```

When I clicked button "Update", [screenshoot error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPJR.png)

How can I solved it? Plase help me.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your form tag like this :

```
<form  method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/moredetails/update/'.$new->proyek_id.'/'. $new->laporan_id.'/'.$new->id_fisik_rencana) }} " >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array of parameters:

```
{{ url('/moredetails/update', [$new->proyek_id, $new->laporan_id, $new->id_fisik_rencana]) }}
```